# An equality derived by Poincare and Holder inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I'm reading a paper concern with regularity of stable solutions to elliptic PDE. One of step in his proof make me confuse and highly suspect it is wrong. It's
$$\frac{1}{|B_r|}\int_{B_r}|u–\bar{u}|dx\leq C\left(\int_{B_r}|Du|^2dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\quad for~r\in(0,1)$$
where $\bar{u}$ is average in $B_r$ i.e.
$$\frac{1}{|B_r|}\int_{B_r}udx$$
The author said just use Poincare and Holder inequality to obtain the conclusion, but I believe there will be a $r^{–1}$ cannot be control.
Thanks for comments or solutions.

Comment: which paper is this from ?

Comment: It's alright if $C$ is allowed to depend on $r$.

Comment: What dimension are you working in? The formula could be homogeneous in $\mathbb{R}^2$ maybe.

Comment: We intent to obtain a universal bound, so C should only concern with n. And we need $n\geq 3$.

Comment: I guess that it is correct. The constant increases with $r$. Since $r\le 1$, taking the constant corresponding to $B_1$ gives a uniform bound. This would be false if $r\in(0 , \infty)$.